# Joomla Discussion - When to create a plugin, when to create a component?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have been learning to develop my own plugins and components for joomla! 2.5.

After a couple of months of developing features for my site, I am starting to realise that some of the components I have created could have probably been just as effective if I'd developed them as a plugin for com_content or com_user.

My question is what's the best way to decided if a full component is needed and when is it ok to use one or multiple plugins to give the same functionality.

My feeling at the moment is that plugins are a much nicer way to go due to them being self contained. Maybe I've answered my own question, and components are needed when interaction between elements is more complicated, where as plugins can be used for very modular functions.

Anyone else have a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components and Plugins are completely different types of extensions.

Components are applications/systems that will appear in the content area such as VirtueMart and where the articles are shown. Consider them as software for you computer.

Plugins are there to manipulate Joomla and/or there extensions it's using. They contains functions that are associated with trigger events. So in a nutshell, they are there to extend the functionality of an existing extension.

So so answer your question, have a think about what you are creating and if will be an aplication or something to extend functionality.

Hope this helps

Comment: So then at what point, for example if you were developing, would you build a plugin to extend com_content rather than build/use a new component e.g. com_k2. Because at the end of the day they have the same functionality!

Comment: You made the decision based on the complexity of what you are trying to do. In order to make com_content do the same thing as K2 would take at least a dozen plugins if not more. You want to try to minimize the number of plugins you are using to keep your site bloat-free and fast.

Comment: You can use plugins to create complex plugins, but there is a balance - that's why its not as simple as you have said in your answer.

Comment: feel free to make changes to my answer or write another one.